# WebRTC Kurento Docker Image on EC2

Tags: javascript, docker, streaming, webrtc, kurento

I have setup a local Kurento MediaServer with Docker and tested the provided application locally on my home network. But at my work place it doesn't work. The clients can reach the web apps but I think the mediaserver IP-address is not accessible from outside the installation network. How can I deploy the provided mediaserver from Kurento with Docker to an EC2 instances?

Comment: Did you ever get that solved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but due to the fact that you are behind a NAT, you'll be needing to configure a STUN server in your KMS. You can uncomment the lines referring to STUN server in the config file `/etc/kurento/kurento.conf.json`

```
 "WebRtcEndpoint" : {
     "stunServerAddress" : "173.194.66.127", // Only IP address are supported                                  
     "stunServerPort" : 19302
    // turnURL gives the necessary info to configure TURN for WebRTC.                                                        
    //    'address' must be an IP (not a domain).                                                                            
    //    'transport' is optional (UDP by default).                                                                          
    // "turnURL" : "xxx:xxx@12.20.173.78:3478"
    // "pemCertificate" : "file"                                                                                             
  },
```

I'd suggest you take some time studying WebRTC, and why you need a STUN/TURN server in [some cases](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/?redirect_from_locale=es)

Comment: I'm facing similar problem, namely have running Kurento srv at home and other dev is not able to see video streaming on the other side of globe. I have properly configured STUN server and additionally exposed an example app deployed locally on node.js via tunneling tool https://pagekite.net and I've got stuck...

Comment: @damax You can check if your STUN server is correctly configured by looking at the SDP answer returned from KMS. If it is working, you should see some `srflx` candidates there.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the NAT / STUN / TURN related issues, you'll want to reconsider doing this in production because Docker and UDP are not a happy marriage, given UDP access needs to span a number of ports normally. You can get round some of this with --net to host but obviously this comes at some cost to security and possible service conflicts.